# Protocol composition

Tags: provable-security, universal-composability

I have been trying to wrap my head around different definitions of protocol security (stand alone, sequential composition, parallel composition, universal composition) and how the proofs of any of these cases are obtained. However, at current state I find it quite complicated. Can you recommend any good lecture materials or maybe survey articles that would help to get into this topic?

Comment: I assume you've read Canetti's "paper" that has already grown to a small book: http://eprint.iacr.org/2000/067

Comment: At least I have tried reading it. My hope was that maybe there is a more easily readable introduction material.

Comment: You got a view recommendations already, so hopefully there was something useful for you. But anyway, reference recommendations are offtopic here.

Answer (score 1):

*Protocols for Authentication and Key Establishment* [1] By Colin Boyd is considered very good book. That has plethora of examples, proofs etc. in very understandable language and format.

Another book is *Modern Cryptography Theory And Practice* [2] by Wenbo Mao. Few chapters have very good introduction to designing protocols in attack-fix cycles.

and few more

1. Boyd, Colin, and Anish Mathuria. Protocols for authentication
   and key establishment. Springer, (2003).
2. Wenbo, Mao. "Modern cryptography: theory and practice." Publisher: Prentice Hall PTR,
   Copyright: Hewlett Packard (2004).
3. **Cremers, Cas, and Sjouke Mauw. Operational semantics and verification of security protocols Berlin: Springer, 2012.** This is an excellent single book that covers all the aspects needed in great detail and rigor.
4. Bella, Giampaolo. Formal correctness of security protocols. Heidelberg: Springer, 2007.

Comment: I could not see anything about the (e)CK model in the index of the first book. The eCK-model is from 2007 non-extended one is from 2001, however, the book is from 2003.